# My program does not stop on condition

Tags: c, string

So- my program does not stop on condition (str2[o] != '+')
So if anyone knows why and how to fix it it will help me ( :.

this is My code -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char str3[9]= "2+48*4+7";
char str2[9];

int w =0,o = 0;

for(w = 0; w < 9; w++)
{
    if(str3[w] == '*')
    {
        while(str2[o] != '+')
        {
            str2[o] = str3[w];
            o++;
            w++;
        }
    }
}

printf("%s\n",str2);

}
```

Thanks to everyone who can see and tell me why the program does not stop on condition that specified.

Comment: What will this code do and the expected result?

Comment: while(str2[o] = str3[w] != '+')
        {
            o++;
            w++;
        }

Comment: or simply while( (str2[o++] = str3[w++]) != '+');

Answer (score 1):

At the moment `+` will be copied to str2, o index will point to the next char, which most probably won't be `+`, so you condition will never be true. This could be possible solution  :

```
    do
    {
        str2[o] = str3[w];
        o++;
        w++;
    }
    while(str2[o-1] != '+' );
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
while(str2[o] != '+')
```

provokes undefined behaviour as `str2`'s elements had not been properly initialised before being read.

To fix this do

```
char str2[9] = "":
```

Comment: and the same will happen when you try to print it, as it is not zero terminated.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(str2[o] != '+') 
    {
        str2[o] = str3[w]; 
        o++;
        w++;
    }
```

Assume o == x. You're assigning value to str2[x]. In while, you are seeing if str2[x+1] == '+', but str2[x+1] is empty.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the last updated value in str2, but you are checking the next value which is not initialized with a character so the loop will keep on repeating itself. you can do this:

```
while(str2[o-1] != '+'){

     str2[o] = str3[w]; 
    o++;
    w++;
}
```

Comment: when o=0; `str2[-1] != '+'` ?